# txt file convert into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file with three features:

```
file_name.txt: 
[{"x":1599235200000,"isValid":true,"y":10830027},
{"x":1599321600000,"isValid":true,"y":10883502},
{"x":1599408000000,"isValid":true,"y":10915511}]
```

Using python read the txt file and make it into dataframe.

The output I wish I have is only x and y:
x is the timestamp and should be 1599235200.000 --> (2020, 9, 4, 16, 0)
y is the numerical value, and the output should convert into the dataframe.

```
dataframe:
x                   y
2020-09-04         10830027
2020-09-05         10883502
2020-09-06         10915511
```

Comment: Please attach the code of what have you tried. It will be easier to know where are you stuck

Answer (score 2):

It looks like JSON data. pandas has a method [`read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) to read JSON files.

```
df = pd.read_json('file_name.txt')
df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'])
df
```

**Output:**

```
                           x  isValid         y
0 1970-01-01 00:26:39.235200     True  10830027
1 1970-01-01 00:26:39.321600     True  10883502
2 1970-01-01 00:26:39.408000     True  10915511
```